# Modify the text of Range selector in high stock

Tags: highcharts

[image: High Stock range selector]

I am using range selector in Highstock chart but I don't know how to update the text of range selector button (text:"zoom" ) in the image.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set [rangeSelectorZoom](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#lang.rangeSelectorZoom) option, like this:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  lang: {
    rangeSelectorZoom: "Test"
  }
});
```